# React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null

Tags: reactjs

I do not understand why React is giving no problems when I'm checking for data before outputting it, but when I don't use the if/else (but there IS data) React gives me this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    post: null
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    const id = this.props.match.params.post_id;
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        post: res.data
      })
    })
  }
  render() {
    const post = (
      <p> {this.state.post.body} </p>
      ) 
      
    return (
      <div>
       <p>{post}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Posts;
```

comparing to:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    post: null
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    const id = this.props.match.params.post_id;
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        post: res.data
      })
    })
  }
  render() {
    const post = this.state.post ? (
      <p> {this.state.post.body} </p>
      ) : ( <p>Loading post....</p>
      )  

    return (
      <div>
        {post}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Posts;
```

Help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Well, there is no data until the Ajax call has finished.

Comment: I do not understand the timing. When I add a console.log for the render() methode and also for the componentDidMount() method, then also in the second example, where there is a check for data, the render() is executed first, and after that comes the componentDidMount(). This should cause the second example to also not have any data. But in reality, there is data outputted.

Comment: That is (almost) correct, the second example does not have any data initially. The difference is that the second example checks for that possibility and shows the "loading..." message if there is no data. The timing is 1) componentDidMount runs and triggers the Ajax call, 2) initial render with the default state, 3) some point later the Ajax call finishes and changes the state, 4) state change triggers a new render with the new data from the Ajax call.

Comment: I had look at your answer, but when I add console log, like this: componentDidMount(){
    const id = this.props.match.params.post_id;
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        post: res.data
      })
      console.log('comp') 
    })
  }
  render() {

    const post = this.state.post ? (
      <p> {this.state.post.body} </p>
      ) : ( <p>L.</p>
      ) ;
      console.log('render') the console gives me: render, render and comp, in that order. So componentdidmount seems to come last?

Comment: No. The Ajax call completes last. You have the console.log inside the function that's called only after the Ajax call has completed. You need to read up on what Ajax is and how asynchronous functions work.

Comment: OK, I understand the problem now. I didn't know that the script would block when it meets 'post = this.state.post', I thought it would skip it and try again during the re-rendering, when the data is there. Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized `post`with null, which means it does not contains any value.

When you are trying to access `this.state.post.body` this makes program think that there is data inside `post` which looks like, `post = {body: "some data"}`.

But in your case that `body` element does not exists, and you get the message saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null`, in simple language, it is trying to say, that the object that you are trying to read is empty, so there is not a value having key `body` and that is why you are getting that error.

In second case, you are doing following clever conditional rendering

```
const post = this.state.post ? (
      <p> {this.state.post.body} </p>
      ) : ( <p>Loading post....</p>
      )
```

what is does that, it looks at the `this.state.post` and sees if it contains any data, initially it is `null` which is falsy value, so in the first render when there is no data, the value of `const post = <p>Loading post....</p>` and you see `<p>Loading post....</p>` first for a brief amount of time.

While this is happening, the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method is running Axios call, and when it gets the data from the URL that is provided to it, it updated the state of `post` by

```
this.setState({
        post: res.data
      })
```

and when that state gets updated, the rerender occurs, and this time, `this.state.post` is not empty, it is now containing the data that your axios call got from the URL, and this time when you do conditional rendering

```
const post = this.state.post ? (
      <p> {this.state.post.body} </p>
      ) : ( <p>Loading post....</p>
      )
```

`const post`  is equal to `= <p> {this.state.post.body} </p>` because `this.state` is not empty anymore.

Here is what is happening step by step:

[image]

Step 1: When the app runs first, the render is getting executed, at this moment, the value of `this.state.post` is `null` as shown in the picture. this is the step you will get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null` because as shown in the picture, `this.state.post` is null in the first render cycle.

Step 2: Now the execution of `componentDidMount()` will executed, initially, we can see that before Axios call, the value of `this.state.post` is still null.

Step 3: Axios call returns the post from the given URL, and just after that it updates the state of `this.state.post`.

Step 4: As soon as the `this.state.post` gets updated, the rerender takes place and we can see the `render` method gets fired and we see the data stored in `this.state.post` this time, unlike `null` that we got in Step 1.

I hope this picture and step by step operation helps you understand why both examples given in question behave the way they do.

You can find this example here, check out console output: [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jkyv2s?embed=1&file=src/App.js)

Comment: I do not understand the timing. When I add a console.log for the render() methode and also for the componentDidMount() method, then also in the second example, where there is a check for data, the render() is executed first, and after that comes the componentDidMount(). This should cause the second example to also not have any data. But in reality, there is data outputted.

Comment: OK, I understand the problem now. I didn't know that the script would block when it meets 'post = this.state.post', I thought it would skip it and try again during the re-rendering, when the data is there. Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score -1):

Your data is not loaded.
Check first:

```
return (
  <div>
   <p>{this.state.post && this.state.post.body}</p>
  </div>
);
```